# Invariant theory

Tags: invariant-theory

My question might be an easy or could be a bit complicate and classic. Actually I am trying to understand why the discriminant of a binary quadratic form is a "the fundamental invariant" under $GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$-action i.e any other invariant is a polynomial of the discriminant. Also I am interested to know about general binary forms.  More precisely I would like to know the number of fundamental invariant of binary form of degree n under $GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$-action.

Comment: What is your question? 

Comment: @Ryan: Well, I guessed I have explained it. I want to know how many fundamental invariants exists for the $GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$-action on binary form of degree n. For example for binary quadratic and cubic form, there exists only one invariant which is the discriminant. I hope I have made it clear.    

Comment: What is a fundamental invariant?

Comment: Have you tried reading a textbook on quadratic forms?  What is the domain and range of your quadratic form?  In my opinion your question is too vague but perhaps someone will understand your context.  

Comment: Dear Ryan, I don't think the question is vague, although I don't have a good answer off the top of my head.  

Comment: Dear Qiaochu,  A fundamental invariant is a member of a generating set for the full ring of invariants.

Comment: Dear Qiaochu: By "Fundamental invariant" I meant the invariants which other invariants are generated by those. To make it more clear, for example, the discriminant of binary quadratic form is the fundamental invariant, because other invariant are a polynomial of th discriminant. But quartic binary forms has two fundamental invariant. 

Comment: Dear Ryan: Well I have some basic knowledge of quadratic forms, but I have not encountered with this concept before, this is why I have posed my question. You might consider all binary forms are real. To make my question more accessibly, let consider real quintic binary form i.e binary form of degree five with real coefficient, then basic invariant theory tells us the ring of $GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$-invariant is finitely generated. So I am interested to know how many elements generate this ring.      

Comment: I'm guessing you're dealing with quadratic forms that can be interpreted as homogeneous polynomials with ?integer? coefficients, so it's a classical number theory context?   The reason for my confusion is quadratic forms come up quite often in topology where they're taking values in $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ or in various modules over $\mathbb Z$.  Anyhow, that's the source of my confusion. Sorry for the distraction. 

Comment: What is your definition of an invariant. If it has to be polynomial in the coefficients of the form, then you can speak of *the fundamental invariant* of a quadratic form. But otherwise, we know that there are binary quadratic form with the same discriminant, that are not congruent. This can be seen by looking at the integers that they represent. For instance $x^2+xy+3y^2$ represents $3$ but $x^2+3xy+5y^2$ does not. Yet they have the same discriminant $-11$.

Comment: @Denis Serre: if I may, I wonder whether your comment is predicated on a conflation of two different notions of "fundamental system of invariants".  You seem to be intending it in the sense "a collection of properties of an object which collectively determine it up to isomorphism", whereas the OP means something very different: "the subring of elements fixed under the action of a group on a [polynomial, classically] ring".  (Along with Emerton, I don't find the question to be vague.  In fact, I would be interested in reading answers to it.)  

Comment: You should have a look at "Classical Invariant Theory" by Olver.

Comment: @M.B.: may I ask why? or what do you want to do with the number of invariants?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the number of generators for the invariants of binary forms is a classic and very hard problem in invariant theory. For forms of small degree one can find a description in Hilbert's book on invariant theory (ISBN 978-0521449038). In the 19th century it was solved for forms of degree at most 8, and it has recently been pushed to degree 10 in http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jsc.2010.03.002 using computer calculations (where one needs 106 generators). The latter link gives the history of the problem in more detail.

Comment: Perhaps one should add to this that the polynomial invariants for $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ are the same as for its Zariski closure which consists of the matrices whose determinant has a square equal to $1$. This connects up the question to classical invarant theory.